# How to build a loop that allows a user to input positive and whole numbers and ends when 0 or negative numbers are input

Tags: c#

Hello good people.

So I am struggling a little with the while/for/do while loops as I am having trouble understanding their structure.

And that causes me to have some issues with my homework assignment , what I need to do is a write a code for the following:

I need a program that allows a user to input only positive and whole numbers , the program also calculates their sum and shows the result for each input in the console ( for example the user inputs 1 and than 2 and than 3 and than 4 the program will show the result as 10).

The program will end if the user has input 0 or a negative number.

I can only use for / while / do while.

My experience is really with only the basic stuff like int , double , loop , string , etc'

I can't really wrap my head around it very much and I would love to get some ideas and assistance.

I've tried but got stuck at the beginning has I have no idea how to start with it

edit:
I've really just dabbled with the idea because I have no idea how to start , I've made this, it was no good

```
        int number, i=1 , min;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter only positive WHOLE numbers to calculate");
        number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        while (i <= number)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is the smallest number: " + number);
            i++;
        }
```

edit: I did this, but I wonder if there's a better way

```
        int number, sum = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter only positive WHOLE numbers to calculate");
    start:
        number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


        while (number > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("This is your number : " + number);
            sum += number;
            Console.WriteLine("The sum is: " + sum);
            goto start;
        }

        while (number <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number bigger than 0");
            break;
        }
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to show us what you have tried so far, with code?

Comment: Yes, I just fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loops are for code that repeats. In your task, input and addition repeat, so put them in loop. `while` and `for` loops check the condition before executing loop body, and `do` checks after.

Your algorithm is like that:

1. Read input.
2. Check if it's positive, if it's not, exit.
3. Add it to sum.
4. Repeat.

So you should check the condition in the midst of loop. You can use `break` to exit loop early. Since you neither check condition in beginning nor end, just write an infinite loop.

```
int n, sum = 0;
while (true) {
    n = int.Parse (Console.ReadLine ());
    if (n <= 0) break;
    sum += n;
}
```

---

Updated. Yes you can shorten your code.

> ```
> int number, sum = 0;
>
>     Console.WriteLine("Please enter only positive WHOLE numbers to calculate");
> start:
>     number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
> ```

You put a repeating statement outside of loop. It forced you to use a label. Labels can easily make your logic **very** difficult to read.

> ```
>     while (number > 0)
>     {
>         Console.WriteLine("This is your number : " + number);
>         sum += number;
>         Console.WriteLine("The sum is: " + sum);
>         goto start;
> ```

You exit the loop indefitinely, so that's no difference between `while` and `if` here.

> ```
>     }
>
>     while (number <= 0)
>     {
>         Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number bigger than 0");
>         break;
> ```

And the same again.

> ```
>     }
> ```

Remember to use loop when something repeats and don't use when nothing does.

```
Console.WriteLine ("Please enter only positive WHOLE numbers to calculate");
int n, sum = 0;
while (true) {
    n = int.Parse (Console.ReadLine ());
    Console.WriteLine ("This is your number : " + number);
    if (n <= 0) {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter a number bigger than 0");
        // actually he won't get a chance to enter it. Why to ask him then?
        break;
    }
    sum += n;
    Console.WriteLine("The sum is: " + sum);
}
```

Comment: I wrote something a little longer but I guess it works, I wonder if I can shorten it a little?

Comment: I've edited it in my initial post , please look at it there.

Answer (score 0):

1 way of doing it:

```
  int number, i=0 , min=1; // min is the minimum value, i is the sum, number is the input you give



    while (i <= min)// checks if its lesser than zero
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter only positive WHOLE numbers to calculate");
    number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        i += number;
        Console.WriteLine("This is the sum: " + i);
    }
```

Other way of doing it:

```
    int number, i=0 , min=1; // min is the minimum value, i is the sum, number is the input you give

    while (true)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter only positive WHOLE numbers to calculate");
    number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        if(i<=min)
           break;
        i += number;
        Console.WriteLine("This is the sum: " + i);
    }
```

Comment: while does not need a increment, if you dont have a use for it. All it needs is a condition which in your case, is to check if the input is lesser than zero than ignore the loop.

Comment: With this current iteration it just loops with the same number x amount of times ( the amount that the user has input ) and the program ends, and it's always showing the same number ( if the user has input 4 it will say " this is the sum : 4 " until the program ends )

Comment: Fixed it. Thats because the console print and input retrieving codes were outside the while block. This wont fix the code completely. The first input is still not validated. you can fix it further by seeing how you can validate the check on the first iteration

Comment: Try it out a little while. If you still need help do let me know.

Comment: I did this , I wonder if there's a better way (edited my post)

Answer (score -1):

I think the best thing to do is read the documentation:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/while
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/do

Comment: I know how to use the while and do loops on a basic level , probably better than the explanation in the doc, but I don't have a general idea on how to implement that code idea into reality using them.